# Expose a projected Entity stored on AzureTable via OData

Tags: c#, odata, asp.net-web-api2, azure-table-storage

I want to expose an entity using an OData endpoint. The data is stored on an Azure Table and has millions of records. I don't want to expose to the clients the PK and RK but I want to run optimized queries.

Let's make an example.
I have the following OData Entity

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    public int Age {get;set;}
}
```

And I've this entities in an AzureTable as the following structure:

```
public class PersonEntity : ITableEntity
{
    public string PartitionKey {get;set;}
    public string RowKey {get;set;}
    public int Age {get;set;}
}
```

I'd like to rewrite the queries that I get from my OData client and to forward them to the underlining AzureTable endpoint.

http://mydomain/odata/Person?$filter=FirstName eq 'John'&$orderby=LastName desc

I'd like to check all the security details and forward it to the AzureTable mangling the query.

Any idea on how to achieve that other than 'string replace'?